Capture Incoming HTTP request using composable in Nuxt 3
Is it possible to capture incoming request data from the index.vue page in Nuxt.  I read in the documentation that index.vue is the default page when a Nuxt app is invoked. I want to be able to capture if a POST request is sent when invoking the application. Is that possible and how would that work. The useRequestEvent captures the IncomingMessage but it does not have the body of the request

I wrote a composable that uses useRequestEvent and then get the data from the ReadableStream
